# Layer won't show on OL map

Tags: openlayers

I am new to OL and I'm trying what I thought was a pretty simple thing. I would like to see a second layer that shows lat/lon points.  Is the code below the correct way to achieve it, or am I missing something obvious?

```
const projection = getProjection('EPSG:4326');
const view = new View({ projection });
const mySource = new VectorSource({ wrapX: false });
const myLayer = new VectorLayer({ source: mySource, visible: true });      
this.map = new Map({target: 'myMap', layers: [
   this.getMyTileLayer(), // Shows up fine
   myLayer // AFAIK I don't see anything plotted
], view});

// Called externally
addToMap(lat,lon) {
  // I can console.log here and I have verified the lat/lons coming in are correct
  const feature = new Feature(new Point(fromLonLat([lon,lat])));
  this.mySource.addFeature(feature);
}
```

Update:
  If I add the following code to my addToMap function, I now see my marker, but the original TileLayer has disappeared. I'm assuming these issues are somehow related?

```
this.map.getView().animate({ center: fromLonLat([lon, lat]), zoom: 10});
```

Comment: Feature geometry should be in the view projection, which is EPSG:4326, so there's no need for the `fromLonLat()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. How else would I pass in lat/lon coords? What part(s) of the code needs to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are related

Your view projection is EPSG:4326

```
const projection = getProjection('EPSG:4326');
const view = new View({ projection });
```

You are converting your feature coordinates from EPSG:4326 [lon,lat] which is correct for the view to EPSG:3857

```
const feature = new Feature(new Point(fromLonLat([lon,lat])));
```

and you are centering the EPSG:4326 view with EPSG:3857 coordinates

```
this.map.getView().animate({ center: fromLonLat([lon, lat]), zoom: 10});
```

You should either change your view to EPSG:3857 or leave your coordinates as [lon, lat]

Comment: I think that's better but I still have the same issues. If I center it. the tile layer is missing (404s, maybe due to WMTSTileGrid code not shown) If I do not center it, I do not see the new layer

Comment: The view won't display anything unless it has a center and zoom or resolution, but for an  EPSG:4326 projection it should be  `this.map.getView().animate({ center: [lon, lat], zoom: 10});`

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to that before posting, but no luck :(

Comment: FWIW I don't want to center on it other than for testing. I just used centering to ensure I could see the lat/lon. Ideally I want to see the lat/lon appear on the map without repositioning the users view (they are zoomed in appropriately to be able to see it)

Comment: I'm basically trying to replicate this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html

Comment: If the WMTS displays when you use EPSG:3857 coordinates suggests it should be a EPSG:3857 layer but has been set up as EPSG:4326.

Comment: The WMTS does not display when I use EPSG:3857. It looks like a blank page with zoom controls

Comment: nm, I got it now. I didn't see that when the fromLonLat call is removed I needed to reverse the variables from lon lat to lat lon.